# Returning length of scope variable in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I want to return the value length of a scope variable who contains an array of objects. Well, my idea was to reduce the html view and to store the variables in my controller. The problem is when I call the value in the console I'm getting always the length 0.

The following code considered the previous view:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body bg-form">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <strong>total:</strong>
            </div> 
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <span class="badge"> {{ nameslist.length }}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body bg-form">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <strong>filtered:</strong>
            </div> 
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <span class="badge"> {{ filteredNames.length }}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
...
<tr ng-repeat="names in filteredNames = (nameslist | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse)" class="show-cursor">
      <td>{{ names.fname }}</td>
      <td>{{ names.lname }}</td>
</tr>
```

These should be the new code:

```
<div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="sResult in searchResult">
        <div class="panel-body bg-form">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <strong>{{ sResult.title }}:</strong>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <span class="badge"> {{ sResult.content }}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Ctrl:

```
$scope.nameslist = CrudService.getAllNames();
$scope.searchResult = [
            {
                title: 'total',
                content: $scope.nameslist.length
            },
            {
                title: 'filtered',
                content: $scope.filteredNames.length
            }
        ];
```

Service:

```
myApp.factory('CrudService', ['ResService',
    function (ResService) {
        return {
            getAllNames: function () {
                return ResService.names.query();
            },
...
}]);

myApp.factory('ResService', ['$resource', 'baseUrl',
    function ($resource, baseUrl) {
        return {
            names: $resource(baseUrl + '/api/names/:Id/:fname', {
                Id: '@Id',
                fname: '@fname'
            }, {
                'update': {
                    method: 'PUT'
                }
            }),
...
}]);
```

How can I return only the number of the array and the filtered number of the array?

Comment: Maybe  you are just trying to evaluate $scope.searchResult.length on the console when you are not in the module context? $scope is not a global variable

Comment: Your controller appears to treating your CrudService as if it were synchronous.

Comment: @Black0ut Why I should do return the length of searchResult.. I need the length of nameslist and filteredNames.

Comment: @DavidL hmm I don't know where the CrudService should do a synchronous treatment.. I mean I need the length of the scope variables only.

Comment: But you can't know that length of a variable that you didn't received yet

Comment: Please post the code of CrudService.getAllNames();

Comment: Produce an MCVE. `{{ nameslist.length }}` should work.

Comment: @StaffordWilliams I've added CrudService in my Post above.

Answer (score 0):

This line does not immediately populate the object;

```
$scope.nameslist = CrudService.getAllNames();
```

From the [angular documentation on $resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource):

> It is important to realize that invoking a $resource object method
>   immediately returns an empty reference (object or array depending on
>   isArray). Once the data is returned from the server the existing
>   reference is populated with the actual data.

You need to bind to the object `$scope.namelist` in your view, or, wait until the promise is resolved and then assign the properties in the success callback.

One solution is as follows;

**Javascript**

```
$scope.searchResult = [{
    title: 'total',
    content: $scope.nameslist // holds a reference to the item returned by CrudService
}]
```

**View**

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <strong>{{ searchResult.title }}:</strong>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <span class="badge"> {{ searchResult.content.length }}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm getting the Array of the objects and return it on the view but that isn't my intention. I want the LENGTH of this array. I've rewritten the view as follows: `<span class="badge"> {{ sResult.content.length }}</span>` and the code in the controller is like your sample code. But how can I return the Length of the variable `filteredNames` Look at ngRepeat in my post above.

Comment: I've updated my answer to have the correct variable names.  As for `filteredNames`, your code doesn't show where you're getting that from.  If you're getting it from a similar place as `getAllNames` (ie: `$resource`) then the same applies, you need to hold the reference in your model returned to the view, and have the *view* bind to the full path of the length: `searchResult.content.length`